# C++ initialized unnamed struct member in constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

example:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A();
private:
    struct {int x, y; } position_;
};
```

my question is: how to init `position_.x` and `position_.y` before the constructor function body? like:

```
A::A()     //init position_.x and position_.y here
{
}
```

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors in this code that are completely unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a normal constructor initializer list:

```
A::A()
    : position_{0, 0}
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it like any data member<sup>1</sup>: in the constructor initialization list:

```
A() : position_{1,2} {}
```

at the point of declaration:

```
struct {int x, y;} position_{1, 2};
```

or both.

---

<sup>1 Assuming you have C++11 or higher</sup>

Comment: Can I not use C++11 feature to achieve my goal?

Comment: Both require C++11+ (no braces in mem-initializers in C++03).

Comment: @LeoLai How would I know what you can use? If you can, you're fine. If not, then you're not fine!

Comment: @Leo - If you have a compiler from 2015, you can likely use features from C++11 as well as from the C++14 standard. If you use Turbo-C++ from 1991, it will work less well.